# $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous and bounded then $f$ attains maximum or minimum?

Tags: functions, continuity, limsup-and-liminf

Is it true that a function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous and bounded then $f$ attains maximum or minimum? I think it's not true but cannot find any counterexample.

Comment: It's not true. You might want to look at some trig functions.

Comment: A counterexample is $\arctan(x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. For a counterexample, consider $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ where $\sup f = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ but the supremum is not attained. Similarly for the infimum.